# JedisPool cannot connect to a telnet redis server

Tags: java, spring, redis, pool, jedis

My redis server is in a VMWare Server, and I can connect redis server from telnet by cli:

`C:\Users\Administrator>redis-cli -h 192.168.0.243 -p 6379
192.168.0.243:6379> get name
(error) NOAUTH Authentication required.
192.168.0.243:6379> auth root
OK
192.168.0.243:6379> get name
"pool zzzzqqqqq"
192.168.0.243:6379>`

In my java code, I can connect to redis server successfully by Jedis.

JedisDemo:

```
    Jedis jedis = new Jedis(constr) ;  
    jedis.auth("root"); 
    String output ;  
    jedis.set( "hello", "world" ) ;  
    output = jedis.get( "hello") ;  
    System. out.println(output) ;
```

But I cannot get connect to redis server by JedisPool:
here is the code:

RedisUtils.java:

```
public class RedisUtils {

private JedisPool pool = null;

private final static String REDIS_IP = "192.168.0.243"; 

private final static int REDIS_PORT = 6379;

public RedisUtils() {
    this(REDIS_IP,REDIS_PORT);
}

public RedisUtils(String ip, int prot) {
    if (pool == null) {
        JedisPoolConfig config = new JedisPoolConfig();    
        config.setMaxTotal(100);  
        config.setMaxIdle(10);  
        config.setMaxWaitMillis(50 * 1000);   
        config.setTestOnBorrow(true);   
        config.setTestOnReturn(true);   
        config.setTestWhileIdle(true); 
        pool = new JedisPool(config, ip, prot, 100000,"root");  


    }
}

public RedisUtils(JedisPoolConfig config ,String ip, int prot){
    if (pool == null) {
        pool = new JedisPool(config,ip,prot,10000);
    }
}

public RedisUtils(JedisPoolConfig config ,String ip, int prot ,int timeout){
    if (pool == null) {
        pool = new JedisPool(config,ip,prot,timeout);
    }
}

public RedisUtils(JedisPool pool){
    if (this.pool == null) {
        this.pool = pool;
    }
}

public String get(String key){
    Jedis jedis = null;
    String value = null;
    try {
        jedis = pool.getResource();
        value = jedis.get(key);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        pool.close();
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        returnResource(pool, jedis);
    }
    return value;
}

public String set(String key,String value){
    Jedis jedis = null;
    try {
        jedis = pool.getResource();
        return jedis.set(key, value);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        pool.close();
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "0";
    } finally {
        returnResource(pool, jedis);
    }
}
...
```

RedisDemo

```
    RedisUtils redisUtils = new RedisUtils();

    redisUtils.set("name", "pool zzzzqqqqq");

    System.out.println("get name : "+redisUtils.get("name"));
```

Result:

```
    redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: Could not get a resource from the pool
at redis.clients.util.Pool.getResource(Pool.java:53)
at redis.clients.jedis.JedisPool.getResource(JedisPool.java:226)
at com.mbg.redis.RedisUtils.get(RedisUtils.java:122)
at com.mbg.redis.RedisDemo.poolTest(RedisDemo.java:25)
at com.mbg.redis.RedisDemo.main(RedisDemo.java:35)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Pool not open
at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.BaseGenericObjectPool.assertOpen(BaseGenericObjectPool.java:672)
at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:412)
at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:363)
at redis.clients.util.Pool.getResource(Pool.java:49)
... 4 more
```

can you tell me why?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you can use the password parameter in your JedisPool instantiation in order to simulate AUTH command.

Try this:

```
public String set(String key,String value){
    Jedis jedis = null;
    try {
        jedis = pool.getResource();
        jedis.auth("root");
        return jedis.set(key, value);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        pool.close();
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "0";
    } finally {
        returnResource(pool, jedis);
    }
}
```